# DynamoDB query `--limit 1` in go sdk?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

What's the go-sdk equivalent of `--limit 1`?

I can do in CLI like:

```
aws dynamodb query 
  --table-name TABLE_NAME
    ...
  --limit 1
```

I wasn't sure how to do this in go-SDK, I tried below:

```
var parameter = &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName: aws.String("TABLE_NAME"),
    KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{...},
    SetLimit: aws.String("1"),
}
response, err := Dyna.Db.Query(parameter)
```

Then I had an error like:

```
$ go test
# _/home/test/
./test.go:48:11: unknown field 'SetLimit' in struct literal of type dynamodb.QueryInput
```

What's the correct way of `--limit 1` in go-SDK?

Answer (score 2):

It should be like:

```
Limit: aws.Int64(1),
```

Found here:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/main/service/dynamodb/api.go#L19470

```
// SetLimit sets the Limit field's value.
func (s *QueryInput) SetLimit(v int64) *QueryInput {
    s.Limit = &v
    return s
}
```

Comment: I needed `Limit: aws.Int32(1)` in GoLang v1.20.5, AWS sdk go v2